# Link command error (link: missing operand after ...)

Tags: shell, hyperlink, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to run a shell script that makes use of the **link** command to recycle a common script so that it can run in several directories.  A script within a subdirectory calls a shared script in a parallel subdirectory named *share*.  The contents of the calling script are just the following (both the calling and shared script are named Allrun):

```
link ../share/Allrun
```

This command is supposed to link this script with the one actually containing the juice within the "share" subdirectory.

Now, this is what I get when the code above is executed:

```
link: missing operand after `../share/Allrun'
Try `link --help' for more information.
```

I am using Ubuntu-12.04LTS.  The scripts I am trying to run are for a validation of a computational fluid dynamics problem.  This is the source of the scripts which I am sure run under different conditions; if you follow the commands within main "Allrun" script you will see what it is trying to do:

http://www.opencae.jp/svn/OpenFOAM-VandV-SIG/AIJ-PWEAB/trunk/CaseB/

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

`link` always takes two arguments: the existing file, and the new file to create as a link to the first.  If what you're trying to do is create a hard link to Allrun in the current directory, you want:

```
link ../share/Allrun Allrun
```

Consider using `ln` instead, which allows you to omit the target and is somewhat more standard.

Comment: rra, Thanks for your quick response. I tried simply substituting the **link** command in the calling script for the **ln** (without changing anything else) and it didn't work.  This is the error message I get from **ln**:`ln: failed to create hard link './Allrun': File exists`

Comment: Ah, okay, that's something different -- that says that there's already a file named `Allrun` in the current directory.  Maybe it's already been successfully linked there?  Or maybe you have an `Allrun` script left over from a previous installation?

Comment: The way the scripts were made, all of them are called "Allrun".  I get the original error message with the virgin version downloaded from the SVN (http://www.opencae.jp/svn/OpenFOAM-VandV-SIG/AIJ-PWEAB/trunk/CaseB/). It is a possibility that they left some unwanted code behind.  But they are also using the "link" command and not the "ln" command.  Is there any circumstance in which this would have worked?

Comment: Using `link ../share/Allrun Allrun` gives me the following error: `link: cannot create link 'Allrun' to '../share/Allrun': File exists`.  It seems the link command with the two arguments tries to replace the script file that is actually calling it.

Comment: There is absolutely no way that you can link multiple scripts with the same name into the same directory with the same name.  I'm not sure what the upstream developers were trying to do (I haven't looked at the code in detail).  The command `link ../share/Allrun Allrun` creates a file named `Allrun` in the current directory that's a hard link to the file `../share/Allrun`; it doesn't do anything at all with the currently running script (unless the current script is called `Allrun`.

Comment: All the scripts have the same name and are in different directories.  It is possible that the contents of the SVN have some remaining garbage from a previous run, although I don't know enough to know what should be there and what not.  The way they have the Link command there is `link ../share/Allrun` which only has one argument and doesn't work for that reason.  There are a parallel set of files that are called "Allclean" that have exactly the same arrangement which is adds to the weirdness of the whole thing.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if they have some sort of link command that comes with the package that does something more complicated than just hard-link the script into a different directory (such as choosing a different name), and what's really going on here is that they're being bitten by a system command with the same name as some helper script they expect to have available.